# October CMS Customization

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I badly need your help with the ff. questions:

1. Can I limit the # of properties/products that an admin can upload?
2. In Settings > System > Administrators, are there any other ways I can limit the # of admin users aside from doing it manually?
3. Can I change the URL for the backend and make it short? (e.g. https://samplewebsite.com/backend/backend/auth/signin to https://samplewebsite.com/admin)
4. Can I change the color of the round “loading” icon?
5. If I clicked on “My Account”
   Can the sidebar be removed/hidden and just show the “Account” tab ONLY?

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all of these, but this reads like a task list from a client. I recommend that you get professional help with these requests by posting on https://octobercmsjobs.com/. The purpose of this site isn't to write your code for you for free.

1. and 2. Yes by hooking into the local model.beforeCreate event and checking against your limit there.
2. Somewhat, you could either add a redirect from admin or change just the first backend to whatever you want with the cms.backendurl config property.
3. Sure, either target it with css or replace it with css
4. You're looking for Backend Menu::setContext

Additionally from the screenshots I saw you post in the discord your install is quite out of date and your first priority should be updating it.